# org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerD ataSource is it threadsafe?

Tags: spring, datasource

We would like to know whether the following data source

org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerD ataSource

is threadsafe and can be used in production environment? Any links to a source that confirms it would be helpful.

regards
aravias

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not use `DriverManagerDataSource` in production. Not because it is not thread safe (I believe it is), but because it does not perform any connection pooling, which results in horrible performance and unnecessary network overhead. See [notes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) in Javadoc.

You should consider using [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) or [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0) data sources, `DriverManagerDataSource` is fine only for testing purposes.

Comment: It's not quite that black-and-white. Connection-pooling isn't always necessary (e.g. mysql connections are very lightweight and fast to set up, Oracle ones are heavy and slow). In low-intensite applications with the right database, `DriverManagerDataSource` is fine.

Comment: If this is the case, I had a look at `DriverManagerDataSource`. As far as I can see, the class itself is thread-safe, as well as its base classes. I assume the underlying `java.sql.DriverManager` is thread-safe as well, but neither classes document this. To be sure, I would suggest using ordinary data source pool implementation configured to shrink (physically close) unused connections the moment they are closed by the application.